# How to rejoin cast session after app restart?

Tags: android, cordova-plugins, google-cast

**I want to re-join an existing cast session after the app has been restarted.**

Eg. On the Youtube app you can start casting some media, force kill the app, start youtube again, and it seamlessly rejoins the cast session.  (It still knows about what you are casting and you can control the session.)

How can I achieve this behavior as well?

I have saved the sessionId, but I can't seem to find a way to see if any route is currently casting the same sessionId.  (I'm not sure if this is the right way to go about it either though.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using [Cast Application Framework (CAF)](https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/migrate_v2/android_sender), in the `onCreate` event, you must call:

```
CastContext.getSharedInstance(activity);
```

This will result in the desired behavior.

The problem for me is that I was developing a cordova plugin and the plugin did not load until well after `onCreate` and `onResume`.  (I believe the searching for and automatically rejoining occurs during `onResume`, so the context was missing this event and not attempting to search at all.)

The solution for me was to get the corodva plugin to load before `onResume`.  I accomplished this by modifying `plugin.xml` to include `<param name="onload" value="true" />`.

```
  <platform name="android">
    <config-file target="res/xml/config.xml" parent="/*">
      <feature name="Chromecast">
        <param name="android-package" value="acidhax.cordova.chromecast.Chromecast"/>
        <param name="onload" value="true" />
      </feature>
    </config-file>
</platform>
```

For everyone:

You can monitor whether is session is re-joined with this code (also in `onCreate`):

```
CastContext.getSharedInstance(activity).getSessionManager().addSessionManagerListener(new SessionListener() {
    @Override
    public void onSessionResumed(CastSession castSession, boolean wasSuspended) {
        // This catches any sessions we are able to rejoin
        setSession(castSession);
    }
}, CastSession.class);
```